# Keep get parameters set when invoking submit_tag in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some state set (the sorting order of columns) that is stored in get parameters, and I have a checkbox form whose value is submitted via (in a haml file)

```
= submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

Is there a way to pass the value of the sort parameter, if any, to the submit_tag method so the sorting is maintained?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would embed sort parameters in a hidden field.

```
= hidden_field_tag :sort_by, params[:sort_by]
```

Then, upon submit, this value will be posted along with the form and will be available in `params` again.